# Subtracting values from different table row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to subtract two values using this method, but it doesn't work for me. Any idea how to subtract this using this way?

```
<td>'.$row['sales']-$row['return'].'</td>
```

Comment: what is the result you get

Answer (score 5):

Wrap it in parentheses:

```
<td>' . ($row['sales'] - $row['return']) . '</td>
```